# How can I specify U in a type expression involving Array<T>.prototype.map<U>?

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following example

```
type Test = ReturnType<Array<string>['map']>
```

the type of `Test` is `unknown[]`.

How can I parameterize the `map` function so that the type of `Test` becomes e.g. `number[]`?

I would expect something like

```
type Test = ReturnType<Array<string>['map']<number>>
```

but this is invalid syntax.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using utility-types like that?

Comment: I've reworded your question to better reflect the exact problem you're having. I'm really surprised that we can't reference `Array<T>.prototype.map<U>` directly in TypeScript (even with concrete types for `T` and `U`), that's weird.

Comment: I wanted to define a function which accepts an argument `callbackfn` with the same signature as for `map`, so I got to `Parameters<Array<string>['map']>[0]` but couldn't get the generics right. I can of course just define it without referencing `map`, but this question became more of a curiosity.

Comment: Right - and now I really wanna know now too!

Comment: In TS4.7 you'll be able to use instantiation expressions to get close to this but it looks like you still have to drop down to the value level in between, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJqpW).  Not sure if there's anything better.

Comment: Posted [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607#issuecomment-1058144708) in ms/TS#47607, not sure anyone will reply there.  Do you want me to write up an answer with this info or am I missing something?

Comment: I would expect this to be doable purely on the type level, but if that's not the case, then your answer is probably as good as it's going to get.